# Specific page script in head doesn't get called first time I navigate on page. Code organization doubts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, code-organization, turbolinks-5

I'm using Turbolinks for the first time and not with Rails (I'm using Django).

### REPRODUCTION

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/dc628a17-3ccd-47b4-9921-8fb332aaebb1

### SOURCE CODE

1. `index.html`:

   ```html
   <html>
   <head>
     <script defer src="/js/index.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     Text and NO <script></script>!
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. `about.html`:

   ```html
   <html>
   <head>
     <script defer src="/js/index.js"></script>
     <script defer src="/js/about.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     Text and NO <script></script>!
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. `index.js`:

   ```js
   import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks'

   Turbolinks.start()
   ```
4. `about.js`:

   ```js
   function drawChart() {
     console.log("I will drawChart() here")
   }

   // drawChart() <--- this is commented on purpose here, with this it works!

   document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', drawChart)
   ```

### THE PROBLEM

If I start from page `/index` and then navigate by link to `/about` nothing happens!

If I now go back to `/index` I can see in console the log: `I will drawChart() here`. So the listener is working.

If I start (refresh on) from `/about` instead it print in console the message so the listener `turbolinks:load` is running the function `drawChart()` on refresh.

### WHAT I EXPECT AND WHAT I DID

I need the call to the function `drawChart()` happens in the first navigation to `/about` too.

So I thought of using a direct call in the file (`drawChart()`, commented in the source code on this issue as you can see) and it works.

But I think this is not the good way to go, especially because if I go on `/about` and refresh the page it's called two times!

It seems to me too hacky.

Isn't?

### WAHT DO OTHER PEOPLE DO

1. Same problem but his solution doesn't work for me: https://candland.net/rails/2019/03/13/rails-turbolinks-not-firing-js-on-load.html

#### THANKS FOR YOUR WORK!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `turbolinks:load` is being fired before `about.js` is loaded. When Turbolinks renders a new page it will add any non-existent scripts to the `<head>` and then trigger lifecycle events e.g. `turbolinks:load`. In this case, it will not wait for every `script` to load before triggering `turbolinks:load`. Here's what's probably happening:

1. `index.html` loads with `index.js`
2. Navigate to `about.html`
3. Turbolinks merges `about.js`
4. `about.js` starts downloading
5. Turbolinks completes the lifecycle and triggers `turbolinks:load`
6. `about.js` finishes downloading and executes

Because `turbolinks:load` was already triggered in 5. the callback in `about.js` won't be called until the next load.

You may want to try including about.js at the bottom of the `<body>` of `about.html`. The `turbolinks:load` listener will not be needed.

Alternatively, try and include your JS in a single file, and perhaps use content of the page to determine when to call `drawChart`. For example:

```
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks'

// about.js content here

Turbolinks.start()

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function () {
  var chart = document.getElementById('chart')
  if (chart) drawChart()
})
```

Comment: I answered here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/489#issuecomment-529434261. Too much long for SO.